# Content of ContentPage not filling entire page - Maui

Tags: xaml, layout, modal-dialog, maui

In my application (for iOS, tested with iPhone 14 Plus) I have a page that I want to show as modal. The problem at the moment is, that when I show it as a modal, the content does not fill the entire page. This is  not a problem at the top of the screen. There is however also space at the bottom that I somehow cannot fill with content. Am I doing something wrong here?

[image]

In the xaml of the page I only defined a background and a border element. As seen here:

```
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 Background="Red">

    <Border Background="{StaticResource DefaultBackgroundColor}" StrokeThickness="0"/>
    
   </Contentpage>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Border`s behavior is not defined until it has a child element.

To fill parent, try:

```xml
<Border Background="{StaticResource DefaultBackgroundColor}" StrokeThickness="0">
  <Grid RowDefinitions="*">
      <!-- whatever you want here -->
  </Grid>
</Border>
```

Grid with row "*" takes all available space.

---

Another possible cause is the [iOS Safe Area](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/layout#iOS-iPadOS-safe-areas).

If you are sure you want to put something there, disable the safe area:

```xml
<ContentPage
   ...
   Background="Red"
   IgnoreSafeArea="True">
```

Or maybe that needs to be on `Grid`. Changing first code snippet:

```xml
...
  <Grid RowDefinitions="*" IgnoreSafeArea="True">
...
```

I see the Red managed to show there already. Anyway, it is worth a try.